# Find indeces with duplicates

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I would find Indeces from array1 in to array2 with duplicates.

```
var array1 =
[ 
 {homeTeam: 'Yokohama FC'},
 {homeTeam: 'Shonan Bellmare'},
 {homeTeam: 'K. Frontale'},
 {homeTeam: 'Cerezo Osaka'},
 {homeTeam: 'Nagoya G.'},
 {homeTeam: 'Gamba Osaka'}
]
```

```
var array2 =
[ 
 {homeTeam: 'Yokohama FC'},
 {homeTeam: 'Shonan Bellmare'},
 {homeTeam: 'K. Frontale'},
 {homeTeam: 'Cerezo Osaka'},
 {homeTeam: 'Nagoya G.'},
 {homeTeam: 'K. Frontale'},
 {homeTeam: 'Cerezo Osaka'},
 {homeTeam: 'Nagoya G.'},
 {homeTeam: 'Gamba Osaka'}
]
```

My output should be :

```
[ 
 {homeTeam: 'Yokohama FC', IndexInArr2: [0] },
 {homeTeam: 'Shonan Bellmare', IndexInArr2: [1] },
 {homeTeam: 'K. Frontale', IndexInArr2: [2 , 5] },
 {homeTeam: 'Cerezo Osaka', IndexInArr2: [3 , 6] },
 {homeTeam: 'Nagoya G.', IndexInArr2: [4 , 7] },
 {homeTeam: 'Gamba Osaka', IndexInArr2: [0]}
]
```

I tried to create a function with poor results

```
function findIndex(array, attr, value){
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i+=1){
      if(array[i][attr] == value){
      return i
      }
    }
    return -1
}
```

Thank you for your eventully answers

Answer (score 0):

You were close! Instead of returning when you find the first occurence, save them in an array and return it only at the end. I've made it so it returns an empty array instead of -1 when it was not found, but you could test on the array's length to still return -1 if need be, but I think that always returning an array is better for such a generic function.

```
function findIndex(array, attr, value){
    const indices = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i+=1){
      if(array[i][attr] == value){
         indices.push(i);
      }
    }
    return indices;
}
```

Comment: I think that this solution is good for a singol array. I tried it but it doesn't work beacuse I have two array. I also tried to innest an annidate for at start function

Answer (score 0):

You could use this approach as well. Run a `map` over `array1` and then compare each items `homeTeam` value with `array2` followed by grouping the indices using `reduce`

```js
const array1 = [
  { homeTeam: "Yokohama FC" },
  { homeTeam: "Shonan Bellmare" },
  { homeTeam: "K. Frontale" },
  { homeTeam: "Cerezo Osaka" },
  { homeTeam: "Nagoya G." },
  { homeTeam: "Gamba Osaka" }
];
const array2 = [
  { homeTeam: "Yokohama FC" },
  { homeTeam: "Shonan Bellmare" },
  { homeTeam: "K. Frontale" },
  { homeTeam: "Cerezo Osaka" },
  { homeTeam: "Nagoya G." },
  { homeTeam: "K. Frontale" },
  { homeTeam: "Cerezo Osaka" },
  { homeTeam: "Nagoya G." },
  { homeTeam: "Gamba Osaka" }
];

const result = array1.map((item) => {
  const { homeTeam } = item;
  const result = array2.reduce(
      (accumulator, current, index) =>
      current.homeTeam === homeTeam ? [...accumulator, index] : accumulator,[]);
  return { homeTeam, IndexInArr2: result };
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @phil Consider upvoting/marking it as correct one if it helped